# Capistrano passing -b flag to git-clone causes error

Tags: ruby, git, capistrano

I recently upgraded Capistrano to 2.15.4. `cap deploy` tried to run this command on the server:

```
git clone -q -b master <URL of my repo>
```

Which resulted in this error message from Git:

```
error: unknown switch `b'
```

Checking the local man page for `git clone`, I don't see the `-b` switch listed. But, on the [man page published online](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html), I see that it's listed as a valid switch. (It enables you to specify a branch.)

Why the discrepancy? Was this switch added in a later version of Git?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was added in git 1.6.5.   The reference in capistrano was added in this commit:
https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/commit/b8ce59ca4022b23d70bff597f3e32b74c818f977

Try:

1. Upgrading git
2. Using a different strategy than shallow-clone

It doesn't look like this requirement has been added to any of the Capistrano docs.